# How to generate node embedding fast and consistant performance?

Tags: graph, vectorization, nodes, embedding

I have a large graph (over 400K nodes) in networkx format. I would need to generate its node (and edge) embedding. I was using node2vec as follows,

```
# Initialize for 256
node2vector = Node2Vec(G, dimensions=256, walk_length=20, num_walks=100, workers=4)
model = node2vector.fit(window=10, min_count=1, batch_words=4)
```

But unfortunately, it is taking ages. Is there any other alternative that I can use to generate embedding for different dimensions (e.g, 64 or 128). Any idea welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: R. Liu, A. Krishnan, PecanPy: a fast, efficient, and parallelized Python implementation of node2vec (2021), Bioinformatics[6] R. Liu, A. Krishnan, PecanPy: a fast, efficient, and parallelized Python implementation of node2vec (2021), Bioinformatics